# Apply function method to a DataFrame to create one list of 2-dim tuples

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

This problem is one that I have created for Stack Overflow which is simpler but the answer should be able to be applied to the more complex dataset that I am trying to solve.
I want to use the apply method on the dataframe using my function to produce one long list of all 2-dim tuples.

Here is the dataset:

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd
from itertools import cycle

data = {'Movie':  ['Shrek', 'The Incredibles','Shawnshank'],
        'Keywords': ['adventure|fun|fiction|ogre|castle', 'heroes|family|fun|entertaining|exciting','prison|emotional|thrilling|entertaining|classic'],
        'Score' : [7.4, 3.4, 9.1]}

dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Movie', 'Keywords', 'Score'])
```

I have created a function which will take a row from the dataset and return a list of 2 dimensional tuples with keywords as the key and the score as the value:

```
def func2(row):
    words = (row['Keywords'].strip('|').split('|'))
    score = []
    i = row['Score'].tolist()
    score.append(i)
    merged = (zip(words,cycle(score)))
    return(list(merged))

func2(dataframe.iloc[0,:])
```

Output:

```
[('adventure', 7.4),
 ('fun', 7.4),
 ('fiction', 7.4),
 ('ogre', 7.4),
 ('castle', 7.4)]
```

I have tried various methods to apply this to the DataFrame to make one long list of 2-dim tuples but thus far none have been successful and I keep getting the error:

```
'float' object has no attribute 'tolist'
```

This is the output I would hope to get once using it on the whole dataset:

```
[('adventure', 7.4),
 ('fun', 7.4),
 ('fiction', 7.4),
 ('ogre', 7.4),
 ('castle', 7.4),('heroes', 3.4),
 ('family', 3.4),
 ('fun', 3.4),
 ('entertaining', 3.4),
 ('exciting', 3.4),('prison', 9.1),
 ('emotional', 9.1),
 ('thrilling', 9.1),
 ('entertaining', 9.1),
 ('classic', 9.1)]
```

I need to use the apply method as the actual dataset I am working with has 500 rows. My goal is then to use the list to create a whole new dataframe.

Any help would be massively appreciated and I hope this is the correct format for a stack overflow post as this is my first one :)

Comment: welcome! your output is a list, of a tuple. would you let us know what is expected output?

Comment: @simpleApp thank you! I have updated the post now to show the expected output

Comment: can try this and then refactor. `result=[]
for ind,row in dataframe.iterrows():
    val_each_row=[(each,row['Score']) for each in row['Keywords'].split("|")]
    result=result+val_each_row`

Comment: Presumably the error occurs in `row['Score'].tolist()`.  What do you think `row["Score']` is?  Are you assuming it's a Series?  The error indicates it's a number, a single value.  If you "keep getting" an error, that means you "keep doing" the same wrong thing.  Pay attention to the error, and try to understand its cause.

Comment: @hpaulj this was the issue. I the original answer sorted that but then the edit has actually made the solution much easier to get with a different method. Thank you for your help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just [split](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html#pandas-series-str-split) on `|` and [explode](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html#pandas-dataframe-explode) the column.

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {'Movie': ['Shrek', 'The Incredibles', 'Shawnshank'],
        'Keywords': ['adventure|fun|fiction|ogre|castle',
                     'heroes|family|fun|entertaining|exciting',
                     'prison|emotional|thrilling|entertaining|classic'],
        'Score': [7.4, 3.4, 9.1]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=['Movie', 'Keywords', 'Score'])

df['Keywords'] = df['Keywords'].str.split('|')

out = df.explode('Keywords') \
    .apply(lambda s: (s['Keywords'], s['Score']), axis=1) \
    .tolist()

print(out)
```

Output:

```py
[('adventure', 7.4), ('fun', 7.4),
 ('fiction', 7.4), ('ogre', 7.4),
 ('castle', 7.4),
 ('heroes', 3.4), ('family', 3.4),
 ('fun', 3.4), ('entertaining', 3.4),
 ('exciting', 3.4), ('prison', 9.1),
 ('emotional', 9.1), ('thrilling', 9.1),
 ('entertaining', 9.1), ('classic', 9.1)]
```

---

Edit: On second look, I see that you're looking "to use the list to create a whole new dataframe".
 Just create the DataFrame directly without using the list step:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {'Movie': ['Shrek', 'The Incredibles', 'Shawnshank'],
        'Keywords': ['adventure|fun|fiction|ogre|castle',
                     'heroes|family|fun|entertaining|exciting',
                     'prison|emotional|thrilling|entertaining|classic'],
        'Score': [7.4, 3.4, 9.1]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=['Movie', 'Keywords', 'Score'])

new_df = df[['Keywords', 'Score']].reset_index(drop=True)
new_df['Keywords'] = new_df['Keywords'].str.split('|')
new_df = new_df.explode('Keywords').reset_index(drop=True)

print(new_df)
```

Output:

```
        Keywords  Score
0      adventure    7.4
1            fun    7.4
2        fiction    7.4
3           ogre    7.4
4         castle    7.4
5         heroes    3.4
6         family    3.4
7            fun    3.4
8   entertaining    3.4
9       exciting    3.4
10        prison    9.1
11     emotional    9.1
12     thrilling    9.1
13  entertaining    9.1
14       classic    9.1
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this has solved the problem! Yes I think that the list step is unncessary

Answer (score 0):

if you need exactly the output you posted then you can do this:

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd

from itertools import repeat

data = {'Movie':  ['Shrek', 'The Incredibles','Shawnshank'],
        'Keywords': ['adventure|fun|fiction|ogre|castle', 'heroes|family|fun|entertaining|exciting','prison|emotional|thrilling|entertaining|classic'],
        'Score' : [7.4, 3.4, 9.1]}

dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Movie', 'Keywords', 'Score'])


def func2(row):
    words = (row['Keywords'].strip('|').split('|'))
    i = row['Score']
    merged = list(zip(words,repeat(i)))
    return(merged)
    
# apply the function to each row   
merged=dataframe.apply(func2, axis=1).tolist()
# convert into one list as desired output
[ item for elem in merged for item in elem]
```